# Date accuracy from calendar POV PHP

Tags: php

This function here basically gets the start and end date and loops through all the monthly dates in between these dates. The problem i am facing is the accuracy if user gives the date as 2018-01-30 (Y-m-d format) and it will skip Feb and instead give a date 2018-03-02 (Y-m-d format) which is not desired. Instead i want the date to be set as 2018-02-28. Also, for dates like 2017-01-31 months which does not have 31 should instead set the date to 30th of their month.

Thanks !

```html
 /**
     * @param $startDate
     * @param $endDate
     * @return array
     */
    public function calculateDaysOfMonth($startDate, $endDate){

        $begin = new \DateTime($startDate);
        $end = new \DateTime($endDate);

       //For including last date in DatePeriod
        $end = $end->modify('+1 day');

        $days = array();

                $interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
                $dateRange = new \DatePeriod($begin , $interval, $end);

                foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
                    $days[] = $date;

                }

        return $days;

    }
```

Comment: Added a working example using Intl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello everyone I solved this issue and now I am providing the solution for such cases where we need consistency from calendar POV.

```html
<?php
 
 /**
 * @param $startDate
 * @param $endDate 
 * @return array
 */
 function calculateDaysOfMonth($startDate, $endDate){

    $begin = new DateTime($startDate);
    $end = new DateTime($endDate);
   


    $days = array();

    //Special case of February
    if($begin->format('d')== 29){


        $end = $end->modify('+1 month');
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
        $dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

        foreach($dateRange as $date){

            if($date->format('m')<02){
                $days[] = $date;
            }

            elseif($date->format('m')==3){
                $days[] = $date->modify('-1 day');
            }
            elseif($date->format('m')%2==0){
                $days[] = $date->modify('-3 day');
            }
            elseif ($date->format('m')%2!=0 && $date->format('m')>3){
                $days[] = $date->modify('-2 day');
            }

        }
        //var_dump($days);die();
            return $days;
    }

    //Months that dont have dates 30 and 31
    else if($begin->format('d')==30 || $begin->format('d')==31){

        $time1 = strtotime($begin->format('Y-m-d'));
        $time2 = strtotime($end->format('Y-m-d'));

        $my = date('mY', $time2);

        $months = array(date('Y-m-t', $time1));
        $f = '';

        while($time1 < $time2) {
            $time1 = strtotime((date('Y-m-d', $time1).' +15days'));

            if(date('F', $time1) != $f) {
                $f = date('F', $time1);

                if(date('mY', $time1) != $my && ($time1 < $time2))
                    $months[] = date('Y-m-t', $time1);
            }

        }

        $months[] = date('Y-m-d', $time2);

        return $months;
    }

    



}

$a = calculateDaysOfMonth('2018-01-29', '2018-06-30');
foreach($a as $b){
var_dump($b);
}
```

The output is this

```html
object(DateTime)#6 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-01-29 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#7 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-02-28 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#8 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-03-29 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#9 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#10 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-05-29 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#11 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-06-29 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [IntlCalendar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php).

```
$startDate = '2018-03-06';
$endDate = '2019-01-30';

$aField = array(
  IntlCalendar::FIELD_YEAR,
  IntlCalendar::FIELD_MONTH,
  IntlCalendar::FIELD_DATE,
);

// start date
$oStartDate = IntlCalendar::createInstance();
$oStartDate->setLenient(FALSE);  // strict interpretation of dates
foreach(explode('-', $startDate) as $i => $v) {
  $v = (int) $v;
  if ($i == 1) $v--;  // months are off by one
  $sField = $aField[$i];
  $iMin = $oStartDate->getActualMinimum($sField);
  $iMax = $oStartDate->getActualMaximum($sField);
  if ($v < $iMin) {$v = $iMin;}
  if ($v > $iMax) {$v = $iMax;}
  $oStartDate->set($sField, $v);
}

// end date
$oEndDate = IntlCalendar::createInstance();
$oEndDate->setLenient(FALSE);  // strict interpretation of dates
foreach(explode('-', $endDate) as $i => $v) {
  $v = (int) $v;
  if ($i == 1) $v--;  // months are off by one
  $sField = $aField[$i];
  $iMin = $oEndDate->getActualMinimum($sField);
  $iMax = $oEndDate->getActualMaximum($sField);
  if ($v < $iMin) {$v = $iMin; }
  if ($v > $iMax) {$v = $iMax; }
  $oEndDate->set($sField, $v);
}

// date formatting
$oFmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
  Locale::getDefault(),
  IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, // datetype
  IntlDateFormatter::NONE // timetype
);
$oFmt->setPattern('yyyy-MM-dd');

// calculate difference, sets values in object..
$oCalcDate = clone $oStartDate;
$iDays = $oCalcDate->fieldDifference($oEndDate->getTime(), IntlCalendar::FIELD_DATE);

// output date range
for ($i=0; $i<$iDays; $i++) {
  echo $oFmt->format($oStartDate) . PHP_EOL;
  $oStartDate->add(IntlCalendar::FIELD_DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: nice example thanks ! I am trying to repeat the date 31 monthly but set it to 30th for months that do not have 31 (same in case of dates 29, 30 in Feb set it to 28th) which i am a bit confused how to do it while integrating your code into mine.

Comment: In short and precise way my query is that a way to select last date of each month within the given start and end dates.